# dependent field in laravel nova 4, dependsOn() method,

Tags: php, laravel

Hi Im using laravel nova 4 and im not able to find any code for dependsOn() method for a dependent field.
I have 2 models (1.type and 2. make)
type belongs to make.
in my resource, field function, i have codes like below
BelongsTo::make('Make'),
BelongsTo::make('Type'),

I want the type dropdown to be dependent on the make selected.
Type has make_id as foreign key.

is there any method i can achieve this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need both dependent fields and relatable filtering. But technically since type already belongs to make you don't actually need to add the Make field.

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#dependent-fields
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/authorization.html#relatable-filtering

```php
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\BelongsTo;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\FormData;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
```

```php
BelongsTo::make('Make'),

BelongsTo::make('Type')
    ->dependsOn('make', function (BelongsTo $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
        session()->put('make_filter', $formData->make);
    }),
```

```php
public static function relatableTypes(Request $request, $query)
{
    if($make = session()->get('make_filter')) {
        return $query->where('make_id', $make);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply do the code below, when `dependsOn` is called, it will also call `relatableTypes`, so you will have it in the request.

The problem with session is, it will keep the value even if you are creating different resource.

```php
BelongsTo::make('Make'),

BelongsTo::make('Type')->dependsOn('make', fn () => null),
```

```php
public static function relatableTypes(Request $request, Builder $query): Builder
{
    // Just in case that request didn't include the input, 
    // like when it's called within `Vue` through `AssociatableController`
    $dependsOn = json_decode(base64_decode($request->string('dependsOn')));

    $makeId = $request->input('make') ?: $dependsOn->make

    return $query->where('make_id', $makeId);
}
```